# Add Ripple / Animation effect to an Android button but keep original customization

Tags: android, xml, android-animation, rippledrawable

I have a custom button, and I need to create a Ripple effect. But after creating I do not know how I could combine the two effects.

I would like to have my original style and when I click add the ripple effect.

Original code before ripple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#EEEEEE"></solid>
    <corners android:radius="5dp"></corners>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#99FFFFFF"></stroke>

</shape>
```

Code ripple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="#f816a463"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#f816a463" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" android:color="#f816a463"></corners>
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#f816a463"></stroke>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Code Button:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btns2teste"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnTestes"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnTestes"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"
        android:text="Botao2" />
```

Image Button before:

[image]

When I created the new style and called in the xml of the button, I can no longer call the effect I created earlier, and it gets a simple button with ripple colors.

I would like to apply the ripple effect but keep the button state in the way I'd like it to be already custom with the border.

I need to find a way to combine the styles.